# Ignore StorageException

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I want to check if a file exists and Ignore the StorageException "File not found"

I try the onFailureListener, but still getting the Error.

```
String path = "Pics/" + list.get(i).getId() + ".png";

StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference();
storageRef.child(path).getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(MyActivity.this, new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
        Glide.with(MyActivity.this).asBitmap().load(uri).apply(requestOptions).into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
            @Override
            public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {

                imageView.setImageDrawable(new SetRoundedImage().setRoundedImage(resource, getResources()));
            }
        });
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(MyActivity.this, new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

        //Log.i(TAG, "Ignore " + e.getMessage());

    }
});
```

Error Exception:

> StorageException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found.  Could not get object",    "status": "GET_OBJECT"  }}
>               java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found.  Could not get object",    "status": "GET_OBJECT"  }}

Comment: if you are using Glide, then use Firebase Ui for storage and use GlideApp directly

Comment: use Log to print the Uri and open it in a browser, whether it exists or not

Answer (score 0):

I think this way is an inefficient way to implement your goal. your goal is to show pictures to imageview from firebase storage. right? then why don't you try [FirebaseUi](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android)?

Here is an example [code](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files)

First, you need to add FirebaseUI dependency with Glide

```
dependencies {
 // FirebaseUI Storage only
 implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:4.3.1'

 implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
 // If you're using Kotlin (and therefore, kapt), use kapt instead of annotationProcessor
 annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
}
```

then create [appmodule](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/storage/README.md) and rebuild your android project, then use GlideApp directly

```
// Reference to an image file in Cloud Storage
StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

// ImageView in your Activity
ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);

// Download directly from StorageReference using Glide
// (See MyAppGlideModule for Loader registration)
GlideApp.with(this /* context */)
        .load(storageReference)
        .into(imageView);
```

Moreover, you can do a circle image crop using this. remember GlideApp can do everything Glide can

```
   GlideApp.with(activity)
                        .load(R.drawable.loading)
                        .apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform())
                        .into(imageView));
```

Comment: The problem is, that I need the resource (image) to convert to rounded, before putting the image in the ImageView. @majuran

Comment: Yes, you can convert round image easily with glide app. Wait I'll show you an example

Comment: Same error when Reference do not exists. I have a List, with and id. The pictures have [id].png ... But some have uploaded their image profile, some, don't. But I have to iterate all the list, and put the image profile in the ImageView of the people who have their image, and a placeholder for the people who don't.